# Auto fill fields when clicking an edit button AngularJS

Tags: php, html, angularjs

**What I must do**: Near each and every user is an `EDIT button`. When I click the `EDIT` `button`, I am redirected to another `page` called `\#\editMember` which has fields where I can edit. Now I am trying that when I click `EDIT`, the fields are filled automatically with the user's information. The information should be placed regarding the user's `id`, so if I click the `EDIT` `button` of John Smith, John Smith's information is `extracted` to the fields.

**My problem is** that when I click the `EDIT` button the fields are not being filled and is giving me the below error.
`ReferenceError: $routeParams is not defined`

**UPDATE**: I found out i had a missing `/` at `.when('/memberEdit/:memberID...`!

**UPDATE 2**: I have updated the post by inserting my `index.html` file paths.

**UPDATE 3**: Fields are not being filled automatically (empty)
               and Errors Solved.
Changed code from

```
    while($row = mysqli_affected_rows($result)) {
    $data = $row;
}
```

to

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data = $row;
    }
```

Thanks!

Here is my code:

HTML (Index page where links for files and etc are stored):

```
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angularApp.js"></script>
    <!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
    <script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
    <link href="libraries/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <title> Music </title>
</head>
```

HTML (MemberList which displays all users with `buttons` to edit):

```
 <thead><tr> <th> Member Image </th><th>Name</th> <th>Surname</th> <th>Status</th> </tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="member in members | filter: searchTerm | orderBy: orderFilter">
                <td> <a href="#/memberDetails"> <img class="image" ng-src="{{member.memberImage}}"> </a></td>
                <td>{{member.name | uppercase}}</td> 
                <td>{{member.surname | uppercase}}</td>
                <td>{{member.dateOfAffiliation | date}}</td>
                <td>{{member.status}}</td>
                <td>{{member.email}}</td>
                <td>{{member.summary}}</td>             

                <td>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteMember(member)"> DELETE </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                <a href="#/memberEdit/{{member.memberID}}"> <button class="btn btn-primary">  EDIT </button> </a>
                <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody> 
    </table>
```

HTML (MemberEdit `page` where fields are filled with member's information):

```
    <div id="container">
<form class="form-group" id="customForms"> <!-- single controller-->
            <label> Name </label> 
                <input id="customFormsInput" class="form-control" ng-model="member.name" type="text" placeholder="Name goes here" required/>
                <br> 
            <label> Surname </label>
                <input id="customFormsInput" class="form-control" ng-model="member.surname" type="text" placeholder="Surname goes here" required/>
                <br> 
            <label> Date of Affiliation </label>
                <input id="customFormsInput" class="form-control" ng-model="member.dateOfAffiliation" type="date" required/>
                <br>
            <label> Status </label>
            <br>
                <select ng-model="member.status">
                  <option disabled="disabled">Choose member status</option>
                    <option value="active">Active</option>
                    <option value="non-active">Non-Active</option>
                </select>
            <br><br>
            <label> Email </label>
                <input id="customFormsInput" class="form-control" ng-model="member.email" type="email" required/>
                <br>
            <label> Summary </label>
                <br>
                <textarea ng-model="member.summary" rows="2" cols="100" type="text" placeholder="Insert text here" required>
                <!-- User text -->
                </textarea>
                <br> <br>
                <br> <br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> Update </button>
            <br> <br> <br>
                <a href="#/memberList"> <button class="btn btn-primary"> Return to Member List</a> </button>
        </form>
</div>
```

AngularJS app (Controller):

```
        app.controller('editMemberCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function() {
        var memberID = $routeParams.memberID;
        console.log(id);
        $scope.updateMessage = "";

        $http.post('model/editMember.php', {'memberID': memberID}).success(function(data) {
            $scope.members = data;
            console.log("Got data of member" + data);
        });
    }]);
```

AngularJS App (routing):

```
var app = angular.module('ScrollingApp', ['ngRoute'])
        .config( ['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/home', {
                    templateUrl: 'view/home.html'
                })
                .when('/promo', {
                    templateUrl: 'view/promoSection.html'
                })
                .when('/contactUs', {
                    templateUrl: 'view/contactUs.html', controller: 'mapController'
                })
                .when ('/aboutUs', { 
                    templateUrl: 'view/aboutUs.html'
                })
                .when('/loginForm', {
                    templateUrl: 'view/loginForm.html'
                })
                .when('/memberList', {
                    templateUrl: 'view/memberList.html', controller: 'memberCtrl'
                })
                .when('/contactUsList', {
                    templateUrl: 'view/contactUsList.html'
                })
                .when('/memberDetails', {
                    templateUrl: 'view/memberDetails.html', controller: 'memberCtrl'
                })
                .when('/memberEdit/:memberID', {
                    templateUrl: 'view/memberEdit.html', controller: 'editMemberCtrl'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/home'
                });
        }]);
```

PHP (To read where id matches the one from the `table`):

```
    <?php
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $memberID = $data->memberID;

    require_once("connection.php");
    $connection = connectToMySQL();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_member WHERE memberID = $memberID";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)
        or die("Error in query: ". mysqli_error($connection));

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Error Given:

```
ReferenceError: $routeParams is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost/music/angularApp.js:124:17)
    at e (http://localhost/music/js/angular.min.js:39:394)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost/music/js/angular.min.js:40:9)
    at http://localhost/music/js/angular.min.js:80:442
    at A.link (http://localhost/music/js/angular-route.min.js:7:268)
    at ea (http://localhost/music/js/angular.min.js:73:293)
    at D (http://localhost/music/js/angular.min.js:62:190)
    at g (http://localhost/music/js/angular.min.js:55:105)
    at http://localhost/music/js/angular.min.js:54:249
    at http://localhost/music/js/angular.min.js:56:79 <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Comment: theres a missing slash in the URL (in the router)

Comment: @Etse Hehe just found it out now, however it is still giving me an error,(I updated topic). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to really tell the source of the problem without seeing the actual returned value.

But what I see: You are expecting an array of members as a result from your query, but the PHP returns one row:

```
while($row = mysqli_affected_rows($result)) {
    $data = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Thus, when you are iterating over the row, you will not have keys and values, but rather a `column of columns`. The column in turn have obviously no such property as `.name` or `.surname`.

Update:

Another issue is, that your PHP code does not return the content type `Content-type: text/json`. Angulars `$http` service will use the content type to decide, if your response string is JSON. Earlier versions of ng used regex to identify json, but that has been given up in favor of the content type containing json (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2973).

So, try adding a content-type header on the PHP response like `application/json` or `text/json` and try again.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Thanks! I have found out that it needed to by `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data = $row;
 }` instead of the `mysqli_affected_rows`. The error is avoided now, but the fields are still empty; without the id's values (name, surname, date and so on) :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the angular-route javascript file in your html. Try adding the following line to your HTML  tag (replace X.Y.Z with the version of AngularJS you are using:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-route.js"></script>
```

For example

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
```

You do not have the complete HTML code, so I cannot verify if this is indeed the issue.

Comment: I already included the file `angular-route.min,js` beforehand though (i downloaded it locally).  I have updated my post with my `index.html`  file, you can have a look if you like please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Apparently my `ng-model` was not matching with the `$scope.members = data;` 
My mistake was that I written `members.name` instead of `member.name`

(I'm a little mad :))